# Where can I find a list of people who used my referral code?

Tags: might-and-magic-duel-of-champions

Am I blind? I've looked all over the place in the menu for the game and in the uplay website.  Where can I see this?

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured this out.  There's a star next to their name in the Friends list.  Apparently my friend failed to use my code properly, which is why I was confused.